# Using Dplyr "group_by" and "Summarise" and a Custom Function to Calculate the Mode of Several Groups

Tags: r, dplyr

Apparently dplyr's summarise function doesn't include an option for "mode". Based on the simple data frame example below, I would like to determine the mode, or most frequently repeating number, for each group of "Category." So for group "A", the mode is 22, for "B", it's 12 and 14, and there is no repeating number for "C".

I found some examples of functions online, but none addressed the situation when there are no repeating numbers in a group. Is there a need for a custom function, or is there a mode option somewhere? I don't want to rely on any other specialized packages just for their mode function. It would be nice to find an elegant and simple solutioin using a combination of base R, dplyr, tidy, etc.

If a custom function is used, it will have to work when there are no repeating numbers, as well as when there are more than one equally repeating number.

Any help would be greatly appreciated! This seems like it should be an easy solutioin in R, so I was surprised to learn that there is no simple summarise_each(funs(mode)... option.

If a custom function is used, please break it down with explanations. I'm still relatively new to R functions.

```
Category<-c("A","B","B","C","A","A","A","B","C","B","C","C")
Number<-c(22,12,12,8,22,22,18,14,10,14,1,3)
DF<-data.frame(Category,Number)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We can use

```
 Mode <- function(x) {
  ux <- unique(x)
  if(!anyDuplicated(x)){
      NA_character_ } else { 
     tbl <-   tabulate(match(x, ux))
     toString(ux[tbl==max(tbl)])
 }
}

DF %>%
   group_by(Category) %>%
   summarise(NumberMode = Mode(Number))
#  Category NumberMode
#    <fctr>      <chr>
#1        A         22
#2        B     12, 14
#3        C       <NA>
```

Comment: Thanks for the fast reply. I tried this function before, but for group "C", which doesn't have any repeating numbers, it returns an 8. Isn't there a way to return something to indicate when there isn't a repeating number? Also, group "B" has two numbers that each repeat twice, so I imagine it returns the lowest number by default. Is there a way to return both numbers if there is more than one mode? This might be asking too much...but I would really like to know when there are no repeating numbers if possible...

Comment: @Mike What do you want for group C?

Comment: That's great, exactly what I wanted. Thanks!